# ¿Es posible agregar una condicion en un append? jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Quiero agregar una condicion en una `append` y nose si sea posible, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
tipo = 0;
   //Forma que quiero
   for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    $('#tabla')
        .append('<tr>'+
                    '<td>BUTTON</td>'+
                    '<td>DATO1</td>'+
                    '<td>DATO2</td>'+
                    (tipo==0)?'':'<td>HOLA</td>'+
                '</tr>');
   }
   //Forma Normal
   if (tipo == 0)
   {
     for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     $('#tabla')
        .append('<tr>'+
                    '<td>BUTTON</td>'+
                    '<td>DATO1</td>'+
                    '<td>DATO2</td>'+
                '</tr>');
     }
   }else{
     for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      $('#tabla')
        .append('<tr>'+
                    '<td>BUTTON</td>'+
                    '<td>DATO1</td>'+
                    '<td>DATO2</td>'+
                    '<td>HOLA</td>'+
                '</tr>');
     }
   }
```

Como se ve, la condicion es: `(tipo==0)?'':'<td>HOLA</td>'` pero al momento de ejecutar el codigo no me muestra ningun dato.

- ¿Hay alguna forma de incluirlo dentro del `append`?

Hago esto porque necesito que el ultimo dato de la condicion aparesca o no. Y no repetir el mismo codigo separandolos.

Espero sus respuestas, gracias

Comment: solo agregalo entre parentesis ejemplo `((tipo==0)?'':'<td>HOLA</td>')`

Comment: Saludos. Prueba (tipo==0)?'':'<td>HOLA</td>' ponerlo ((tipo==0)?'':'<td>HOLA</td>') así aseguras que primero se evalué al condición.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juan:

Aunque lo más correcto sería utilizar el if, podrías cambiar la línea de código de la siguiente forma:

```
( !tipo ? '' : '<td>HOLA</td>')
```

Agrupa lo que evalúas y los datos que quieres asignar en el operador ternario de esta forma y hará el append correctamente al poder evaluar la condición.

Comment: Gracias, a veces la respuesta es muy simple, pero algunas veces no nos damos cuenta.

Comment: Hola, Juan. Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. No te preocupes, suele suceder, tanto a los que tenemos poco tiempo aventurándonos en el mundo de la programación como los que llevan muchos años, lo importante es ser constante. Un saludo.